# Import bootstrap or other html theme to my angular 4 app

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to import the bootstrap theme 3 or other html theme with their dependencies
of javascript files in my angular 4 application. But I can't find anywhere how to import the javascript files.
If finally import them,is safe to use bootstrap 3 or other html theme,without the possibility to break my app?? 
I prefer not use the ng2-bootstrap.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use ng2-bootstrap the easiest way is to import bootstrap from your index.html file like this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng2-bootstrap/x.x.x/ng2-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and just use the normal bootstrap classes in your html